# If I'm tailoring a node to 512mb container, why is --max_old_space_size 460?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, garbage-collection

I have an express app running on heroku.

I am looking to optimize the garbage collection.

The heroku docs say that:

*Node sets a limit of 1.5 GB for long-lived objects by default. If this exceeds the memory available to your dyno, Node could allow your application to start paging memory to disk.*

*To gain more control over your application’s garbage collector, you can provide flags to the underlying V8 JavaScript engine in your Procfile:*

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 server.js
```

*If you’d like to tailor node to a 512 MB container, try:*

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 server.js
```

If the container is 512mb, why would the `--max_old_space_size` be 460 and not 512?

How does this work and is this suitable for production?

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is really complicated, there are complexity memory management algorithms used to collect and clean heap memory. JavaScript heap is made to grow incrementally, in response to increasing demand. If allowed heap memory size is reached, node.js would exit with error.

Following command arguments are:

- optimize_for_size - enables algorithms to optimize heap memory size more often, that process utilizes more CPU resources to keep garbage with less size by cleaning old heap space, including pointer, data, etc.
- max_old_space_size - By default, Node.js (up to 11.x ) uses a maximum heap size of 700MB and 1400MB on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms, respectively. Since v12.7 node.js supports better heap size allocation on container environment.

Configuring the heap size based on available memory ensures that Node.js does not try to use more memory than is available and terminating when its memory is exhausted.

I would recommend on production node.js environment:

- setup node.js restart policy, in case application is crashed unexpectedly
- before deploying on production, evaluate app performance on load with parameter --optimize_for_size turned on and off
- be prepared to post-mortem analysis of a Node.js application
- continuously monitor node.js application performance and resource usage
- keep node.js, and modules up to date, periodically evaluate vulnerabilities and current issues on github on all used modules in your application

Use best practice and stories to evaluate best solutions on production, for example: https://developer.ibm.com/languages/node-js/articles/nodejs-weather-company-success-story/